# Why let x as Float case is not matching in a switch on a Any variable?

Tags: swift, swift3

I have an enum for tagged values (this is from a toy Scheme interpreter project), like this:

```
enum Value {
  case int(Int)
  case float(Float)
  case bool(Bool)
  ...
}
```

I wrote an initializer for it:

```
init?(value:Any) {
  switch v {
    case let v as Int: self = .int(v)
    case let v as Float: self = .float(v)
    case let v as Bool: self = .bool(v)
    ...
    default: return nil
  }
}
```

With that, calling `Value(3)` returns an (optional) Value.int(3), as expected. Bool's and the other types work too.

But `Value(0.1)` hits the default case and returns `nil`.

(Edited for correctness and recommended style. Thank you everyone for pointing those issues out.)

Comment: Where is `v` defined?

Comment: You probably mean `switch value`. Literal 0.1 is `Double` not `Float`

Comment: Luka, my bad. I was changing the code a bit as I transcribed it into my question. It should read "init?(v:Any)...".

Comment: `case let v as Int` was better, the associated variable is not the same as the "switched" variable and there is a `=` missing in the `Bool` line.

Comment: vadian, thanks. I will try to proof-read better before posting my next question. (someone else made an edit with 'value' instead of 'v' and I accepted it.)

Comment: Last nitpicking: Enum cases are supposed to start with a lowercase letter in Swift 3.

Comment: @Dietrich, btw, can you tell, if it's not secret, what problem that enum should solve?

Comment: No secret, just for a toy Scheme(-ish) interpreter. In my implementation of a linked list the `car` of a list is a variable of this Value enum type. The other option I sketched out was having the basic Swift types (Int, String, etc) conform, though extension, to an empty "Value" protocol, using that protocol as the type of the List class' `car` variable. The enum choice, I think, will make the rest of the interpreter code clearer, enabling me to `switch` on the type of a scheme-level variable. A third choice would be to use the `Any` type, I suppose.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The default inferred type for floating point constants is `Double`, not `Float`. It's defined by the swift standard library here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/floatliteraltype using the compiler-known `FloatLiteralType` typealias.

Comment: Thanks, that was concise and illuminating!

Answer (score 6):

The documentation of [type inference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID322) says:

> Swift always chooses `Double` (rather than `Float`) when inferring the
>   type of floating-point numbers.

If you want to use `Float`, you must explicitly cast the literal:

```
enum Value {
    case Int(Int)
    case Float(Float)
    case Bool(Bool)
    case Double(Double)
    init?(v:Any) {
        switch v {
        case let v as Int: self = .Int(v)
        case let v as Float: self = .Float(v)
        case let v as Bool: self = .Bool(v)
        case let v as Double: self = .Double(v)
        default: return nil
        }
    }
}


Value(v: 0.1) //Infer Double > Result: Double(0.10000000000000001)
Value(v: Float(0.0002)) //Specify Float > Result: Float(0.000199999995)
```

Comment: Please include somme explanation as to why your code works

Comment: @milo526 The code says everything clear. Easy to understand.

Comment: As I now understand it, your Float case will never match either, while your Double case catches it. I don't think your code makes that point clear.

Comment: @Dietrich Swift always chooses Double (rather than Float) when inferring the type of floating-point numbers.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that, @william-hu!

Answer (score 1):

Btw, it looks like you want to be able to init your `Value` type with literals, so you may try conforming your type to `ExpressibleBy*` protocols.

Like:

```
extension Value: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
    init(integerLiteral value: Int) {
        self = .int(value)
    }
}

let v1: Value = 42 // v1 == Value.int(42)   

extension Value: ExpressibleByBooleanLiteral {
    init(booleanLiteral value: Bool) {
        self = .bool(value)
    }
}

let v2: Value = true // v2 == Value.bool(true)

extension Value: ExpressibleByFloatLiteral {
    init(floatLiteral value: Float) {
        self = .float(value)
    }
}

let v3: Value = 0.5 // v3 == Value.float(0.5)
```

Comment: Cool suggestion. I saw that and, wrongly it seems, assumed I couldn't conform to many "ExpressibleBy_Literal" protocols at once. I'll try it, thanks!

Comment: Actually, I do like that much better than what I had going. I wish I could 'sub-check' your answer for "providing a nicer alternative to the path I was already on when I encountered the problem that led to my original question".